# Why do vertices appear white instead of the colour in the vertex buffer?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I've created 3 buffers to separate vertex position, colour and index data.

The vertices correctly render as a square but it's white instead of the colour defined in the array `dynamicVertexData`.

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0, but I assume I'm making a general OpenGL mistake.

Can anyone spot it?

```
typedef struct _vertexStatic
{
    GLfloat position[2];
} vertexStatic;

typedef struct _vertexDynamic
{
    GLubyte color[4];
} vertexDynamic;

enum {
    ATTRIB_POSITION,
    ATTRIB_COLOR,
    NUM_ATTRIBUTES
};

// Separate buffers for static and dynamic data.
GLuint    staticBuffer;
GLuint    dynamicBuffer;
GLuint    indexBuffer;

const vertexStatic staticVertexData[] = {

    {0, 0},
    {50, 0},
    {50, 50},
    {0, 50},
};

vertexDynamic dynamicVertexData[] = {

    {0, 0, 255, 255},
    {0, 0, 255, 255},
    {0, 0, 255, 255},
    {0, 0, 255, 255},
};

const GLubyte indices[] = {

    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
};


- (void)setupGL {

    CGSize screenSize = [UIApplication currentSize];
    CGSize screenSizeHalved = CGSizeMake(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);

    numIndices = sizeof(indices)/sizeof(indices[0]);

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // Improves perfromance

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];


    // The near and far plane are measured in units from the eye
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-screenSizeHalved.width,
                                                                     screenSizeHalved.width,
                                                                     -screenSizeHalved.height,
                                                                     screenSizeHalved.height,
                                                                     0.0f, 1.0f);

    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30;

    CreateBuffers();
}

void CreateBuffers()
{
    // Static position data
    glGenBuffers(1, &staticBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, staticBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(staticVertexData), staticVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Dynamic color data
    // While not shown here, the expectation is that the data in this buffer changes between frames.
    glGenBuffers(1, &dynamicBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dynamicBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(dynamicVertexData), dynamicVertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // Static index data
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void DrawModelUsingMultipleVertexBuffers()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, staticBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexStatic), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dynamicBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(vertexDynamic), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)0);
    }

- (void)tearDownGL {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    //glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);

    self.effect = nil;    

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
//    view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X; // Smoothes jagged lines. More processing/memory
    view.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGB565; // Lower colour range. Less processing/memory
    [self setupGL];
}


- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    DrawModelUsingMultipleVertexBuffers();
}

@end
```

Comment: @genpfault GLKBaseEffect from the GLKit framework handles the shaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've enabled and bound the vertex buffers to your `ATTRIB_COLOR` binding point, by using the `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` entry points, but not specified what to do with them.

OpenGLES 2.0 removed most of the fixed-functionality rendering pipeline, so you will need to write a vertex shader to use the vertex buffers.  In 1.X, you'd be able to use the [`glColorPointer`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glColorPointer.xml) entry point to specify vertex colors to the fixed-functionality pipeline.

Comment: Ahh interesting. I'm using a framework in CocoaTouch called GLKit. It gives me an effect object which takes care of the shader side of things...

Comment: @dene: in which case, you'll have to look at the GLKit documentation to see how to hook up the vertex buffers correctly for the effect you have.

Comment: Thanks @sheu! I changed the enums ATTRIB_POSITION and ATTRIB_COLOR to the GLKIT equivalents GLKVertexAttribPosition and GLKVertexAttriColor and the vertices are now coloured.

Answer (score 1):

When you manage to get openGL ES 2.0 running - which can be hard when starting - but you don't get the drawings you want, I definitively recommend running on device, which enables Extra features from XCode to debug openGL

[image]

Then you can :

- Go step by step through your cycle and draw calls, and see color /
  depth buffer images refreshed
- See all the bounded gl objects
- See VAOs content (you can see the actual data it points to, useful to find missing data / pointers)
- programs : you can edit your shaders LIVE on the GPU (gl bound objects -> program : double-click!) useful to polish your shaders

This can also be very useful, if you're curious, to get an insight at GLKit's GLKBaseEffect inner-workings  - which in fact just generates a openGL program, whose specific vertex and fragment shaders code depend on which properties you set...

The property you forgot is GLKBaseEffect `colorMaterialEnabled`

Comment: Useful to know about OpenGL debugging. Are there any light calculations if no light has been set up? I got it working without setting colorMaterialEnabled.

Comment: Damn, wrong guess ! :) `colorMaterialEnabled' must be for when you want texture AND colour. I don't know what are GLKBaseEffect default settings (some `lightModelAmbientColor ` maybe ?)